# Edit React js form fields are not editable

Tags: reactjs

I have an application where I am trying to allow users to update the input text. I have a table when I display users details and each row has an edit and delete buttuns. When the user clicks the "edit" button, I render the form with the auto populated user data from the table, but the input fields don't allow editing.

```
             initialDataState: {
                  username: '',
                  firstName: '',
                  lastName: '',
                  idNo: '',
                  email: '',
                  mobile:'',
                },

            handleChange = async (event) => {
                if (event.target) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  const { target: { name, value }, } = event;
                  console.log('name ', name);
                  this.setState({
                    initialDataState: {
                      ...this.state.initialDataState,
                      [name]: value,
                    },
                  });
              }


      render () {
        const { initialDataState } = this.state;  
        return (
    <MDBCol md="6">
            <InputComponent
                name="Last Name"
                id="LastName"
                label="Passport Number"
                disabled={false}
                value={initialDataState.lastName}
                type="text"
                step="100"
                minLength="13"
                maxLength="13"
                required={true}
                outline={true}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </MDBCol>;
    )
}
```

Comment: probably just change handleChange attribute of the input to onChange

Comment: if (this.props.type === 'text') {
      inputField = (
        <MDBInput
          name={this.props.name}
          id={this.props.id}
          label={this.props.label}
          hint={this.props.hint}
          disabled={this.props.disabled}
          type={this.props.type}
          value={this.props.value}
          required={this.props.required}
          minLength={this.props.minLength}
          maxLength={this.props.maxLength}
          onChange={this.props.handleChange}
          outline={this.props.outline}
        >

Comment: Input component looks like this, do not how to format it properly

Comment: can you share a codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `name="Last Name"` for the `input` which you use when setting the value in the state, but you access the `initialDataState.lastName` when you pass the value to the input.

`"Last Name"` is not the same as `"lastName"`

Changing

```
<InputComponent
  name="Last Name"
```

to

```
<InputComponent
  name="lastName"
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, such a small mistake.